# CSS Pseudo elements not positioned properly on Safari

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I've wrote the following CSS that uses pseudo elements to design a footer.
Looks like it works fine on Chrome & Firefox on windows but on Safari the `footer_il::after` goes on the bottom of the page.

When im adding `margin-top: -20em;` on `.footer_il::after` it's working the way i want it but it obviously breaks on other browsers.

```css
.footer_il::before {
  width: 75px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(134deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(134deg);
  transform: rotate(134deg);
  left: calc(100% - 463px - 85px);
  margin-top: -2em;
}

.footer_il::after {
  height: 54px;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 449px - 63px);
}

.footer_il::before,
.footer_il::after {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: #f7f7f7
}

.footer {
  height: 20em;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="footer_il bg-light">
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="footer_section_1">
        <div class="footer_container">
          <div class="footer_branding">
            <div class ="footer_logo">
              
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_section_2">

      </div>
      <div class="footer_section_3">
        <div class="footer_container">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_section_4">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly isn't working for you? Seems to work for me in Safari, assuming I understood the problem correctly. You could try explicitly setting a 'top' value to the :after element to ensure proper placement.

Answer (score 0):

So just by playing around a bit i ended up with the following result. Thanks to  pschueller for the hint.

I've added the entire footer into a container. Set the class in absolute position and 100% width. Then added inside the ::after class 0 distance from top.

Now it's working on Mac OS Safari. Because there wasn't a top before it was getting outside of it's intended position.

```css
.footer_entire_container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer_il::before {
  width: 75px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(134deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(134deg);
  transform: rotate(134deg);
  left: calc(100% - 463px - 85px);
  margin-top: -2em;
}

.footer_il::after {
  height: 54px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 449px - 63px);
}

.footer_il::before,
.footer_il::after {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: #f7f7f7
}

.footer {
  height: 20em;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<!-- Footer -->
  <div class="footer_entire_container">
    <footer class="footer_il bg-light">
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer_section_1">
          <div class="footer_container">
            <div class="footer_branding">
              <div class ="footer_logo">
              
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_section_2">

        </div>
        <div class="footer_section_3">
          <div class="footer_container">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_section_4">
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
```